# How to use functions in nativeQuery?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I created a query which is supposed to return a date in a certain format.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT function('date_format', c.valid_to, '%Y-%m-%d') " +
        "FROM card c WHERE c.card_id= :card_id", nativeQuery = true)
```

But I get an error like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function('date_format', c.valid_to, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM card c WHERE c.card_id= 3' at line 1

When I tried to write different queries without any functions it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think
`@Query(value = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.valid_to, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM card c WHERE c.card_id= :card_id", nativeQuery = true)`
should work for MySQL.

Using H2 the following does format a date:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT FORMATDATETIME(c.valid_to,'d MMM yyyy') FROM card c WHERE c.card_id= :card_id", nativeQuery = true).
```